# Sails.js more database connection

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

> `Blockquote`

i will planing use more database on same models on sails.Just wanna change db on progress.How can i do it on sails configure

Answer (score 2):

Just change your connection config in `config/connections.js` to the db you will be using, then, in the model set the connection, example:

**Connection**

```
  mysql: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'your-host',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'your-db'
    port: 3306
  }
```

**Model**

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  connection: 'mysql',
  tableName: 'users',
  attributes: {
    user:{
        type:"string",
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true
      },
      password:{
        type:"string",
        unique: true
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: how i change database in progress ? then action database ? i know all up